# ASP.NET Core - serve different HTML file for SPA?

Tags: html, asp.net, vue.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application

### Question

How can I serve different HTML (entry) files for an SPA application (Vue) in ASP.NET Core?

### Explanation

Depending on a condition, I would like to serve a different HTML page (much like a controller would do for a non-SPA). The page would still include the entry point for Vue apps `<div id="app">`, but some other changes should be done before serving the HTML.

I know I somehow have to change the startup.cs file because that renders the HTML with `app.UseStaticFiles()` and `app.UseSPAStaticFiles()`

### Example

**Condition 1** is fulfilled, `base.html` is served from `client -> public -> base.html`

**Condition 2** is fulfilled instead, `special.html` is served from `client -> public -> special.html`

### Code

The basic HTML looks something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but this webpage doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
      continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

The important parts of startup.cs looks like this:

```cs
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

// ....

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

// ....

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        endpoints.MapToVueCliProxy(
            "{*path}",
            new SpaOptions { SourcePath = "ClientApp" },
            npmScript: "serve",
            regex: "Compiled successfully");
    }

    // Add MapRazorPages if the app uses Razor Pages. Since Endpoint Routing includes support for many frameworks, adding Razor Pages is now opt -in.
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

// ....

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeking to do this exact thing and have had little luck so far

Comment: @whendon unfortunately not, we went with another approach. Good luck!